# Font awesome 4.2.0 TTF on Yosemite

Tags: fonts, font-awesome

**Executive summary**

I have downloaded Fontawesome 4.2.0 from the fortawesome.github.io website, and installed the TTF on OS X Yosemite. The font shows up in and is listed as valid by Font Book. The font does not appear as typeface option in either Pages or Word. The font does appear as an option in Adobe Illustrator CC, but cannot be applied to any objects.

In short, the TTF appears to fail on Yosemite.

**Details**
System profile: MacBook Pro, 8GB; OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite); Adobe Illustrator CC (17.1.0)

I have downloaded the source files twice. I installed (and deinstalled) the fonts both manually (copied the source files directly to /Library/Fonts/) and via Font Book. I ran validation on Font Book and the font lists as valid. Font Book shows a preview of the glyphs without issue. Font Book's diagnostics show no font conflicts, duplicates, or issues on the system.

In particular, this question addresses desktop usage of the font for design purposes and is not about CSS or browser embedding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* Font Awesome uses the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA) to ensure screen
   readers do not read off random characters that represent icons */
```

As a result, certain applications may not identify the set of character maps as a valid typeface.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try downloading it from [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io) after changing its codes. You'll need to [add FontAwesome to IcoMoon via its library](https://icomoon.io/app/#library) first. Before downloading your font, you could assign ligatures to the icons too. Using ligatures, you'd be able to type a word, like "home" to bring up the associated icon. Here's [a video showing how ligatures would work](http://youtu.be/OM60ogIalLk). They're very handy when you want to install and use the font in desktop applications.

Note that by default, IcoMoon doesn't include Latin letters in your font. Therefore, while you're typing a ligature, you may not see anything on the screen. But once you finish the word, the icon would appear. The font you see in the video I linked to contains those Latin characters. They were manually added.

You could also download IcoMoon's free ligature font from here: https://dribbble.com/shots/1857996-Ligature-Icon-Font?list=users&offset=0

Ligatures are great when it comes to desktop usage of icon fonts. But they are underrated and very few people know about them. I'm trying to spread the word.